# Deploy Play 2.2.1 App to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, playframework-2.2

I'm facing issues when trying to add a local git repository to heroku. I created a remote heroku using the heroku create command.

```
$ heroku create
Creating falling-wind-1624... done, stack is cedar
http://falling-wind-1624.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:falling-wind-1624.git
Git remote heroku added
```

I however do not see the "Git remote heroku added" on my console. I'm not sure if this is the reason behind what I'm experiencing when I tried to deploy my Play app to Heroku.

Even doing

```
$ heroku git:remote -a falling-wind-1624
```

does not show anything and later when I type git remote -v, I do not see the heroku git repo added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't see the remote listed, but you can add it by doing:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:falling-wind-1624.git
```

If you then run `git remote -v` you should see an entry for heroku.